# error: member access into incomplete type 'WINDOW' (aka '_win_st')

Tags: c++, ncurses, member-access

I have problems accessing _maxx, it says: ./ScoreBoard.hpp:20:38: error: member access into incomplete type 'WINDOW' (aka '_win_st')
mvwprintw(score_win, 0, score_win->_maxx - 10, "%11llu", score);
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/curses.h:322:16: note: forward declaration of '_win_st'
typedef struct _win_st WINDOW;

this is my code:

```
#pragma once

class Scoreboard {
  protected:
  WINDOW * score_win;
  public :
  Scoreboard(){

  }
  Scoreboard(int width, int y, int x){
    score_win = newwin(1, width, y, x);
  }
  void initialize(int initial_score){
    this->clear();
    mvwprintw(score_win, 0, 0, "Score: ");
    updateScore(initial_score);
    this->refresh();
  }
  void updateScore(int score){
    mvwprintw(score_win, 0, score_win->_maxx - 10, "%11llu", score);
  }
  void clear(){
    wclear(score_win);
  }
  void refresh(){
    wrefresh(score_win);
  }

};
```

Comment: `WINDOW` is an [opaque data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type). You should not really access internal data of it, only use the functions.

Comment: Strange, the tutorial I followed was doing like I did, thank you btw

Comment: That would personally make me start to wondering about the quality of that tutorial. The good thing is that there are *many* tutorials and references about ncurses. :) For example [this one](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) which I've used myself many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in a comment, `WINDOW` may be opaque.  That is a configurable feature of ncurses, which is used in the MacOS SDK.  Toward the top of `curses.h`, you may see

```c
/* These are defined only in curses.h, and are used for conditional compiles */
#define NCURSES_VERSION_MAJOR 5
#define NCURSES_VERSION_MINOR 7
#define NCURSES_VERSION_PATCH 20081102

/* This is defined in more than one ncurses header, for identification */
#undef  NCURSES_VERSION
#define NCURSES_VERSION "5.7"
```

The *opaque* feature was added in [March 2007](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20070303):

```
        + add NCURSES_OPAQUE symbol to curses.h, will use to make structs
          opaque in selected configurations.
```

Rather than use members of the `WINDOW` struct, there are functions which let you read the data:

- [`getmaxx`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_legacy.3x.html) does exactly what you want, but it is intended for legacy applications (such as BSD curses)
- [`getmaxyx`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getyx.3x.html) is the X/Open Curses equivalent which combines `getmaxx` and `getmaxy`.

X/Open Curses does not specify whether `WINDOW` (or other types) is opaque, but it does not mention the struct members such as `_maxx`.  Portable applications should prefer the functions which are standardized.